# How can I convert this script of sqlserver to mysql with the same logic?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, sql

[image]

I have this script in sqlserver but how can I use this logic to mySQL.. it has different syntax. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: post code instead of image. And maybe add what you have tried

Comment: also give the source data and desired output, it'll be much easier to give the solution based on that

Answer (score 1):

The following should help you to use the `RANK()` in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
      SELECT [Street], [Flood],
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
          (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
          ORDER BY [FloodCount] DESC [Ranking]
      FROM
      (SELECT [Street], [Flood], COUNT([Flood]) FROM 
      [Worklog].[dbo].[Flood]
      GROUP BY [Street], [Flood]
       ) a
    ) b
WHERE [Ranking] = 1
```

For more, see this: [RANK() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql)